# How can I read and get notified a computed property of a class in cocoa macos?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

In `NSWindow` class there is a computed property called `isVisible`, I am creating a custom `NSWindow` and i am calling it `MyNSWindow` so I want look the value change of `isVisible` for `MyNSWindow`, for example the value should be false before window get available in screen, and after that the value should be true, so I want observe this value change, how can i do this? Also I am **not** looking for an answer with Combine.

This is my code:

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    private var window: NSWindow!
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        window = MyNSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.title = "No Storyboard Window"
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
        window.center()
        
    }

}


class MyNSWindow: NSWindow {
    
 
    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has made it difficult to reliably be notified when a window becomes visible or hidden. I've done some investigating for my own project, and here's what I've discovered:

- Apple's recommended solution is to set an [`NSViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller#) as the window's [`contentViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419615-contentviewcontroller#). Override the view controller's [`viewWillAppear`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434415-viewwillappear) or [`viewDidAppear`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller) method to be notified when the window becomes visible. Override the view controller's [`viewWillDisappear`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434483-viewwilldisappear) or [`viewDidDisappear`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434416-viewdiddisappear) method to be notified when the window becomes hidden.

  I know this is Apple's recommend solution because I opened a feedback (in 2016) requesting a public `windowWillShow` notification and was told:

  > Our more modern way of doing this is to use Storyboards with a View Controller; the contentViewController will get a viewWillAppear — this is the hook you should be using now.

  As far as I know from very limited testing, this method is reliable, so it may work well for you. I have an existing app with many windows that were implemented without  `contentViewController`s that I do not wish to retrofit, so this doesn't work well for me. Also, you can only apply this to windows you create—not, for example, to the window created by `NSAlert`.
- `visible` is not KVO-compliant.
- There are no documented notifications posted when `visible` changes from `false` to `true`.
- The [`NSWindow.willCloseNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419400-willclosenotification#) is supposed to be posted when `visible` changes from `true` to `false`, but it doesn't get posted when a window presented as a sheet is dismissed.
- It should be possible to use [Cocoa Bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000167-BBCFBCAG) to  bind to `visible` (using the `NSVisibleBinding` constant), but the binding is not updated when a window presented as a sheet is dismissed. It is also annoying and obscure to implement.
- There is no single, public “funnel” method you can override on `NSWindow` to be notified. The [`orderOut(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419660-orderout), [`orderFront(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419495-orderfront), and [`orderBack(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419204-orderback) methods do go through [`order(_:relativeTo:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419672-order), but [`orderFrontRegardless()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419444-orderfrontregardless#) does not. Sheet presentation and dismissal do go through `order(_:relativeTo:)`, so if you never use `orderFrontRegardless()`, making an `NSWindow` that overrides `order(_:relativeTo:)` may be a good solution for you. You will not, however, be notified of the appearance and disappearance of windows created by AppKit for you, such as the window created by `NSAlert`. If you create any `NSPanel`s, you'll also want to create an `NSPanel` subclass.
- AppKit posts a number of undocumented notifications when windows change visibility, that are posted reliably even for sheet presentation and dismissal. Two of these are named `_NSWindowWillBecomeVisible` and `NSWindowWillOrderOffScreenNotification`. Use at your own risk.